# How to start a new process in an existing Dokku dockerfile based deployment

Tags: dockerfile, dokku

I have a rails app that is deployed in Dokku and was working fine, I wanted to add sidekiq, as the documentation recommends is to add a new Procfile, I did but I cannot get the worker to start.